# i can't push on my git branch, everything is up-to-date, but nothing is pushed?

Tags: git, github

I am very confused why I cannot push on my branch, so I am trying to push but it says:

> Branch feature/style set up to track remote branch feature/style from
>   origin. Everything up-to-date

when I use git branch I am on my desired feature/style branch. I also used git pull it says already-up-to-date. but when i commit and push, nothing is pushed? help?

Comment: What is the output when you issue the `git status` command?

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda it says:
On branch feature/style
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/style'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: That means there are no unstaged changes or commits to be pushed. To confirm whether there is an issue or not, change some file and issue the `git status` command again and check the output

Comment: Check what is your remote branch last commit and if you have it in your local branch. It can help you to understand what is happening.

Comment: But if everything is up to date, **do you need to push *at all***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
git pull origin feature/style
git push origin feature/style
```

Answer (score 0):

git-pull - Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch

```
git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]
```

git-push - Update remote refs along with associated objects

```
git push [--all | --mirror | --tags] [--follow-tags] [--atomic] [-n | --dry-run] [--receive-pack=<git-receive-pack>]
       [--repo=<repository>] [-f | --force] [-d | --delete] [--prune] [-v | --verbose]
       [-u | --set-upstream] [--push-option=<string>]
       [--[no-]signed|--signed=(true|false|if-asked)]
       [--force-with-lease[=<refname>[:<expect>]]]
       [--no-verify] [<repository> [<refspec>…​]]
```

Reference

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

For your case

```
git pull origin feature/style
git push origin feature/style
```